# Daubechies scaling function

Tags: implementation-details, wavelet-analysis

In *Mathematica* in wavelet package with the following codes

```
Phi[x_, j_, k_] := 2^(j/2) WaveletPhi[DaubechiesWavelet[3], 2^(j) x - k]
```

*Mathematica* computes `Phi` for various values of $x,j,k$.
How does *Mathematica* do this computation?
My guess is cascade algorithm. If it is cascade algorithm, again how *Mathematica* does this computation because until now i have seen cascade algorithm just for $j=0$ and $k=0$.
If *Mathematica* does not use cascade algorithm what is the algorithm?

Comment: `Trace[Phi[x, 3, 4]]` might give some indication. Not that I really follow the details of what it shows, but it shows a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Unless I'm missing something, your question does not make sense. The [cascade algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascade_algorithm) is an iterative solution to

$\phi(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} c_k \phi(2 x - k)$,

which computes $\phi(x)$ *approximately* at *dyadic points* $x=k\times2^{-j}$, to whatever resolution you choose for the initial approximation. The definition

$\phi_{j,k}(x)=2^{j/2} \phi(2^{j} x - k)$

only requires the ability to compute $\phi(x)$ for at these *dyadic points*.

Indeed, you can recursively compute $\phi(x)$ for any *rational* $x=p/q$ *exactly* in terms of the filter coefficients $c_k$.